# Groovy script on Jenkins doesn't see BUILD_NUMBER variable

Tags: jenkins

I have Jenkins on my local computer and I am trying to make my project work on it. Recently it worked on another jenkins server and I want to make it work just like back then without changes.

When I am starting pipeline it ends with error:
22:52:09 Caught: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: BUILD_NUMBER for class: Jenkinsfile

Why it doesn't see BUILD_NUMBER? It always worked before.
Script is without changes, there are just accessing this variable like this in script:

`burl='http://localhost:8080/job/' + JOB_NAME + '/' + BUILD_NUMBER + '/'`

And it always worked before. Why it says now that BUILD_NUMBER is undefined property?